# naming files in a shared cloud file store

Tags: filesystems, cloud-storage

We are going to set up a shared cloud file store (using OwnCloud, but that probably doesn't matter it'd apply to DropBox or any shared network folder too).

It will be used by a lot of people on a lot of different devices and operating systems (OSX, iOS, Android, Linux, Windows XP - Windows 10). Access is possible through a mobile app or on desktop through an app that syncs the files with a local folder (probably all based on WebDav) and via the browser.

With this is mind should we follow any naming conventions for the store files so all systems will be able to handle the files well? For example should we replace whitespace with "_" or limit the length of the file names? Or should we avoid file names in the same folder that only differ in case?

What else is there to consider?

Comment: All common file systems allow spaces in file names, and graphical file managers deal with them like any other name: it is only in command-line handling that spaces cause complications, because spaces delimit parameters. You should restrict the use of other punctuation characters: `-` and `_` are fine, but I can't speak for all of the others, and `/`, `\` and `:` are definitely to be avoided. It is probably best not to use accented characters, because some people may have difficulty typing them.